# How to find index positions of numbers in an array on a condition?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an integer array..
and I will input a number
And I have to find out the index positions of two numbers such that the sum of the numbers
is equal to the input number.

I did it with the following code

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindIndex {

    int a[] = { 1, 7, 6, 5, 12, 2, 3, 11 };

public void findingIndex() {
    Arrays.sort(a);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the sum of two selected numbers from the array");
    int i = sc.nextInt();
    for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++){
        for(int k=j+1;k<a.length;k++){
            if(a[j]+a[k]==i){
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
                System.out.println("The indexes of the elements are"+j+"and"+k);
            }
        }
    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FindIndex fi = new FindIndex();
    fi.findingIndex();
    System.out.println("end of the program");
}
```

}

The output is

```
Enter the sum of two selected numbers from the array
14
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12]
The indexes of the elements are1and7
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12]
The indexes of the elements are2and6
end of the program
```

**Now i want to achieve this using only *one for loop***??How to do?

Comment: Khm... you want to solve an O(n^2) problem with just one loop (and I presume you mean an O(n) loop)? The only way is shifting the complexity into the space domain---an O(n^2) memory structure.

Comment: if you sort it you will not get the correct index of the original array you will get the index of the sorted array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in O(n * log n) time this way.

```
public static int[] findSum(int[] values, int sum) {
    Arrays.sort(values);  // O(N * log N)
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length() - 1; i ++) { // O(n)
        int remainder = sum - values[i];
        // O(log N) and assuming you can't use the same value twice.
        int pos2 = Arrays.binarySearch(value, i + 1, values.length, remainder); 
        if (pos2 >= 0)
            return new int[] { i, pos2 };
    }
    return null;
}
```

So the total order is O(N log N) + O(N) * O(log N) or just O(N log N)

Answer (score 5):

Since your array is already sorted, you can create two indexes, one starting from the begining and one from the end. If the current sum is inferior than the number to find, increment the first index otherwise decrement the second.

```
public static void findingIndex() {
         Arrays.sort(a);
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter the sum of two selected numbers from the array");
         int i = sc.nextInt();
         int index1 = 0; 
         int index2 = a.length-1;
         while(index1 != index2){
            int sum = a[index1] + a[index2];
            if(sum == i){
                System.out.println("Found with "+index1+" "+index2);
                index1++;
            }
            else if (sum < i){
                index1++;
            } else {
                index1 = 0;
                index2--;
            }
         }
}
```

The time taking to sort runs in `O(nlogn)` and the complexity of the while loop will be  <del>`O(n)`</del>, `O(n²)`, but it still use one loop.

So the overall complexity of the algorithm will be `O(n²)`.

This can be easily translated into one for loop :

```
for(int index1 = 0, index2 = a.length-1; index1 != index2;){
            int sum = a[index1] + a[index2];
            if(sum == i){
                System.out.println("Found with "+index1+" "+index2);
                index1++;
            }
            else if (sum < i){
                index1++;
            } else {
                index1 = 0;
                index2--;
            }
}
```

Comment: The complexity of the while loop is O(n) as you will inspect each element once in the worst case. Overall complexity is O(n*long(n)) as this is the complexity of the sorting. But I am not sure you're not missing some solutions. I have a feeling this algorithm will miss some. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @peter.petrov Yes I said this is `O(n)` for the while loop (`O(n/2) = O(n)`). And I'm pretty sure that I won't miss some cases.

Comment: "The time taking to sort runs in O(nlogn) and the complexity of the while loop will be O(n/2) so O(n) (correct me if i'm wrong)." Well, there's no O(n/2) here, theoretically O(n/2) == O(n).

Comment: @peter.petrov Yes so the overall running time is (`O(nlogn) + O(n) = O(nlogn)`)

Comment: All I am saying is that the O(n/2) looks weird and wrong here.

Comment: The problem is that that you should set `index1 = 0` when you decrement `index2` as you don't know how far you need to back track.

Comment: @PeterLawrey This was my intuition too. But I wasn't sure. So the second loop then becomes O(n*n).

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes I think you're right. So the overall complexity is `O(n²)` yes... I failed !

Comment: @user2336315 You can use the fact you are searching for `sum - a[index1]` in a sorted array, see my answer. ;)

Comment: @downvoter Comment ? The op says `Now i want to achieve this using only one for loop?` So my answer is correct, just not the most efficient.

Comment: @user2336315 Anyway. I downvoted as it was logically wrong. I did not see you added this "index1 = 0; index2--;" Edit your answer once more so I can remove my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Any scenario there is a optimum level, we can't simplify further beyond that level. You can try following.

```
    Integer a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12} ;
    List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the sum of two selected numbers from the array");
    int in = sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        if(list.contains(in-a[i]) &&(list.indexOf(in-a[i])!=i)){
            System.out.println("The indexes of the elements are"
                                        +i+"and"+list.indexOf(in-a[i]));
        }
    }
```

But `contains()` method it self has `for-loop`.

Comment: You can store the value of indexOf() and not call contains().  BTW indexOf is O(N) as it uses a loop and the two matching indexes could be the last two.